using getElementsByName() together with document.getElementById() or alternative approach?
I am trying to find all HTML tags with a specific name "name" inside an element with a specific id.
document.getElementById("myid").getElementsByName("name");

throws error getElementsByName is not a function
The sample code is:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="myid">
        <p name="name">first name</p>
        <p name="name">first name</p>
    </div>
    <p id="result">RESULT</p>
  <script>
    let el = document.getElementById("myid")
    let names=el.getElementsByName("fname");
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = elements[0].innerHTML;
  </script>
  </body>
</html>

I saw somewhere that unlike other functions the 'getElementsByName' is limmited to 'Document' scope only and does not exist in any other scope.

is this true?
what alternative approach should I use instead of 'getElementsByName'?


To answer the questions:

1: is this true?

Yes

2: what alternative approach should I use instead of 'getElementsByName'?

The alternative approach to document.getElementById("myid").getElementsByName("name"); would be
document.querySelectorAll('#myid [name="name"]')
3: The alternative to the code fragment would be
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="myid">
        <p name="name">first name</p>
        <p name="name">first name</p>
    </div>
    <p id="result">RESULT</p>
  <script>
    let el = document.getElementById("myid")
    let names=el.querySelectorAll('[name="fname"]');
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = elements[0].innerHTML;
  </script>
  </body>
</html>

4: I don't see what elements even is, I guess it's  meant to be names[0].innerHTML


yes
you could use querySelector

and keep in mind, that the attribute name is usually used on formular elements. In your case I'd suggest using class:
 <p class="name">first name</p> 


Thanks for helping the user out! When you tell him to use e.g. a querySelector, please tell him also how to use it. :- So, elaborating on your answer would make it way more helpful.
